# import interface in mystrings.d.ts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, localization

I want to add multiple languages to my spfx web part.

Now I want to import some interfaces to my `mystrings.d.ts` declaration file.
But when I do that it breaks the definition and I get a lot of errors like:

[image]

My question is if it's possible to import interfaces to my declaration file for my strings so that i don't have to write these definitions on my own?

Comment: `import some interfaces to my "mystrings.d.ts"` what do you mean by this? It is confusing. Are you using this interface in other TSX/JSX file?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below steps for adding multiple language in SPFX webparts:

1. Within "loc" folder you will see a file named "mystrings.d.ts". At first add property here like below:

```
declare interface ITestWebPartStrings {
  WebpartTitle: string;
}
```

2. There is a file for english language named "en-us.js". If you want to 
   add another language you have to create another file. For example if 
   you want to add Norwegian language then you have to create "nb-NO.js" file.
3. After that add the property in "nb-NO.js" file for Norwegian language.
   And for english language add property within "en-us.js" file as like below:

```
define([], function() {
    return {
        "WebpartTitle": "YourTitle",
    }
});
```

4. Now you have to import in your file.

```
import * as strings from 'TestWebPartStrings';
```

5. Now you can show "WebpartTitle" using "strings.WebpartTitle". This is the process to add multiple language.

```
let wpTitle = strings.WebpartTitle;
```

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted.*

Comment: First, thaks a lot. I think i didn't described my problem exactly. I know how to add multiple languages to my project. The probblem is that i e.g. use the fabric ui calendar and want to set the calendar strings into my language files. therefore i added the "ICalendarStrings" into my mystrings.d.ts file. But therefore i have to import the interface. But then i get the errors from above.

Comment: You are welcome. Now your problem is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to localize your SharePoint Framework web-part to use it for different languages then you can create multiple javascript files for each languages which will have definitions for properties of your web-part.

Follow below official documentation by Microsoft for the same:

[Localize SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts).